# Obfuscate Python and decode stacktraces

Tags: python, obfuscation

My task: casual obfuscation to prevent code from being easily reused. Just obfuscating variable names would be fine.

Are there any tools that allow the following?

1. Obfuscate Python 3 code.
2. Generate sourcemaps.
3. Decode exception stacktraces.

I would like to avoid anything involving complex custom compilers like Cython, i.e. something very complex and susceptible to lagging behind/diverging from the official Python language.

Comment: Can you detail a bit more, why you want to obfuscate your code? For example, do you want to avoid professional reverse engineering or do you want to avoid students to use intermediate solutions?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I want to prevent my distributed Python code from being "forked" and easily reused. Minification (with variable names mangling) alone would be sufficient for me, but available solutions don't seem to support stacktrace decoding (like JS sourcemaps).